# Rails 3 scope issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Can you please point me whats wrong with the below scope. I am writing the scope to get only distinct transaction ids.

```
         scope :unique_transactions,  -> (txnid){ where( "DISTINCT Trasaction ID", txnid )}
```

Comment: what is this `Trasaction ID`?

Comment: Its a column name I have in helper
TRANSACTIONS = ["Merchant Name", "Transaction ID", "Payment Mode","Amount","Status","Transaction Fee","Discount","Additional Charges","Added On"]

Comment: try this `scope :unique_transactions, -> (txnid) { where('Transaction ID = ?', txnid).select(:txnid).uniq }`

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I use distinct instead of uniq. Reason, I don't want to fire multiple queries.

Thanks for your help

Comment: `Uniq` is alias for `distinct`, distinct is added in rails 4. And you are using rails 3 right? and you are using where query still. how you gonna fire multiple quries?

Comment: Your scope giving me syntax error.

syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN_ARG, expecting keyword_do_LAMBDA or tLAMBEG
...cope :unique_transactions, -> (txnid) { where('Transaction I...

Comment: Try this `scope :unique_transactions, -> { where('Transaction ID = ?', txnid).select(:txnid).uniq }`

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Please add it to the answer. Will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 scope :unique_transactions, -> { where('Transaction ID = ?', txnid).select(:txnid).uniq }
```

you was using `DISTINCT` which was added in `rails 4`, instead of it use `uniq`.
Refer to below link for more clarification 
[docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields)